# Why is copy constructor chosen over move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I was looking at the following example regarding move constructor/assignment:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx

I have modified it a little by adding a swap function to simplify the move constructor/assignment and the copy assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class MemoryBlock
{
public:

    // Simple constructor that initializes the resource.
    explicit MemoryBlock(size_t length)
        : _length(length)
        , _data(new int[length])
    {
        std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = "
                  << _length << "." << std::endl;
    }

    // Destructor.
    ~MemoryBlock()
    {
        std::cout << "In ~MemoryBlock(). length = "
                  << _length << ".";

        if (_data != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << " Deleting resource.";
            // Delete the resource.
            delete[] _data;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock& other)
        : _length(other._length)
        , _data(new int[other._length])
    {
        std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock&). length = "
                  << other._length << ". Copying resource." << std::endl;

        std::copy(other._data, other._data + _length, _data);
    }

    // Copy assignment operator.
    MemoryBlock& operator=(MemoryBlock& other)
    {
        std::cout << "In operator=(const MemoryBlock&). length = "
                  << other._length << ". Copying resource." << std::endl;

        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    // Retrieves the length of the data resource.
    size_t Length() const
    {
        return _length;
    }

    // Move constructor.
    MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other)
        : _data(nullptr)
        , _length(0)
    {
        std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = "
                  << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;


        *this = std::move(other);
    }

    // Move assignment operator.
    MemoryBlock& operator=(MemoryBlock&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "In operator=(MemoryBlock&&). length = "
                  << other._length << "." << std::endl;

        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(MemoryBlock& first, MemoryBlock& second)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first._length, second._length);
        swap(first._data, second._data);
    }

private:
    size_t _length; // The length of the resource.
    int* _data; // The resource.
};

int main()
{
   // Create a vector object and add a few elements to it.
   vector<MemoryBlock> v;
   v.push_back(MemoryBlock(25));
   v.push_back(MemoryBlock(75));

   // Insert a new element into the second position of the vector.

   v.insert(v.begin() + 1, MemoryBlock(50));
}
```

Now when I run the code I have the following output:

```
In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = 25.
In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = 25. Moving resource.
In operator=(MemoryBlock&&). length = 25.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 0.
In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = 75.
In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = 75. Moving resource.
In operator=(MemoryBlock&&). length = 75.
In MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock&). length = 25. Copying resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 0.
In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = 50.
In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = 50. Moving resource.
In operator=(MemoryBlock&&). length = 50.
In MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock&). length = 25. Copying resource.
In MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock&). length = 75. Copying resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 75. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 0.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 50. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 75. Deleting resource.
```

What I don't understand why sometimes the copy constructor is called over the move constructor?

If I remove the move constructor definition, and declare it as default:

```
// Move constructor.
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other) = default;
```

Then I get the right output:

```
In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = 25.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = 75.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 75. Deleting resource.
In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = 50.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 75. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 50. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 25. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 50. Deleting resource.
In ~MemoryBlock(). length = 75. Deleting resource.
```

(the constructor calls are missing from output which means the move constructor was used)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the vector operations require that when an exception is thrown that there is no effect (strong exception guarantee). The strong exception guarantee breaks if the move constructor can throw:

Synopsis for `push_back`:

> Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity.
>   If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before
>   the insertion point remain valid. If an exception is thrown other than
>   by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or
>   move assignment operator of `T` or by any InputIterator operation
>   there are no effects.  If an exception is thrown while inserting a
>   single element at the end and `T` is `CopyInsertable` or `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is true, there are no
>   effects. **Otherwise, if an exception is thrown by the move
>   constructor of a non-CopyInsertable `T`, the effects are
>   unspecified.**

Since `T` *is* `CopyInsertible`, it uses the copy constructor instead of the move constructor.

Comment: Did you bold the wrong sentence? I think the sentence right before the one you bolded is more relevant to the rest of your answer. Nice answer though.